# How to solve "error #1: Invalid ruleset provided" when using Spectral to lint an OpenAPI YAML file

Tags: openapi, spectral

I am trying to lint an OpenAPI YAML file using Stoplight Spectral, and following the instructions provided [here](https://docs.stoplight.io/docs/spectral/674b27b261c3c-overview) I get the error "error #1: Invalid ruleset provided" but not any other details.

Comment: Can you please add the error message again please?

Comment: It is just: "error #1: Invalid ruleset provided".

Comment: Create .spectral.yml file manually with the same content without the external quotes and then run the command.

Answer (score 0):

This step:

```
echo 'extends: ["spectral:oas", "spectral:asyncapi"]' > .spectral.yaml
```

encloses the contents in quotes in the generated .spectral.yaml file, which causes the error.  Removing the quotes will leave the value as:

```
extends: ["spectral:oas", "spectral:asyncapi"]
```

which is then understood by Spectral and eliminates the cause of the error.

**NOTE:** this is one of many possible error causes, rulesets themselves might have other internal issues.

Comment: Removing the quotes does not make any difference; it still gives the same error

Comment: Error message is quite generic and ambiguous, it could be caused by other issues (i.e. actual issues in the rulesets).

Comment: Redocly has been much nicer in my exp.  They have a vs code extension and the easiest setup available  `extends: ["recommended"]` in a redocly.yaml file at the root of your workspace and it just works.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Windows Power Shell CD to the npm folder where Spectral installed.
Run as admin if there are errors showing and execute the command
.\spectral lint [OpenAPI file path] --ruleset [ruleset file path]
Eg.
.\spectral lint C:\Path\openapi.yaml --ruleset C:\Path\spectral.yml